# How to merge 3 or more JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I have an issue on how to combine multiple JSON into 1 based on the same key. The key is the 1st Index.

Eg.

```
String data_a = "{\"results\":[[\"1\",\"6000\"],[\"2\",\"5000\"]]\"}";
String data_b = "{\"results\":[[\"1\",\"2000\"],[\"3\",\"5000\"]]\"}";
String data_c = "{\"results\":[[\"1\",\"3000\"],[\"3\",\"6000\"],
[\"4\",\"1000\"]]\"}";
```

Combine string a,b,c to 1 like below:

```
{
 "results ": [
    ["1", "6000", "2000", "3000"],
    ["2", "5000", "", ""],
    ["3", "", "5000", "6000"],
    ["4", "", "", "1000"]
 ]
}
```

Here, I try using gson to convert to Map. But confuse how to do looping and match the key.

```
Map firstObject = new Gson().fromJson(data_a, HashMap.class);
Map secondObject = new Gson().fromJson(data_b, HashMap.class);
Map thirdObject = new Gson().fromJson(data_c, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: Your strings aren't valid JSON unless you surround them with curly braces.

Comment: Thanks, will updated

Comment: Looks like this is not correct -> ["1", "6000", "2000", "3000"],     ......Did u mean  {"1" : [ "6000", "2000", "3000"] ,......},

Comment: Like your purpose also can actually.  I can also to read the result. But the issue is merging the json. I don't have idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Iterate in while loop on condition of until & unless all 3 map in not
>   empty. then put their key values in 4th one map.simultaneously you
>   need to remove particular entry that you are putting in 4th one map.

```
while(!H1.isEmpty() && !H2.isEmpty() && !H2.isEmpty()){

 H4.put(H*) // H1 key
 H*.remove(...) // H1 key

 }
```

you can also get all keyset from map & put in set.

```
Set<int> keys = new Set<int>();
  keys.add(h*.keySet())
```

Iterate over the key.

Comment: tq. But how we match the key? between data a,b, and c.

Comment: get all keys from a map.& then pick these key values from other map

Comment: or you can get key set of mapp maps and add into  set